# is it possible to do multiple runs in Intel VTune Amplifier XE

Tags: profiling, profiler, intel, intel-vtune

Is there a way to run same test(for example Lightweight Hotspots) multiple times in Intel VTune Amplifier XE ??? It is annoying to do multiple clicks to perform a single test. I have looked though documentation, but found nothing.
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things to advice:

1. **First**, once you have set up a project and collected Lightweight Hotspots for it, you should be able to just right-click the project in the Project Navigator (if you are using the standalone GUI) or Solution Explorer (if you are using Visual Studio integration) and click the recently used analysis type to run it again.
2. **Second**, if you are running really many collections, it may be that using amplxe-cl command line is the way to go.  The easiest way to set up the command line to collect the data is to use Get Command Line dialog available from New Analysis window by clicking a button at the right-bottom corner.  A copy-paste to a console should be mostly enough.

A couple of screenshot below should support the two bullets above.

**Running a recent analysis again from Project Navigator:**
[image: Running a recent analysis again from Project Navigator]

**Generating a command line for VTune collection with amplxe-cl:**
[image: Generating a command line for VTune collection with amplxe-cl]

Comment: amplxe-cl is also very helpful when running VTune on machines without graphics capability (e.g. UNIX or Linux without X).  You can display the GUI remotely to get the command line, and then use that command line for subsequent tests.